# How do you test a hypothesis on measurement errors? Is it even possible?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have data which uses $k$ different electronic devices to measure the depth a sea animal is swimming at during an entire day.

The sea depth is divided into $n$ categories, and for each category, we have a proportional response, corresponding to the percentage of time the animal spent in that particular category.

Now, for $n < k$ of these devices, the percentage of time spent in the surface category is consistently **0**. This is obviously an error, since these animals need to resurface in order to take in oxygen.

One can then notice that in the category immediate below the surface, these $n$ devices indicate a much higher percentage than the other devices. For all other categories, no differences are visible.

I would like to test the hypothesis: **For these $n$ devices, the time spent in the first depth category has been added to the time spent in the second category.**

How do I test this hypothesis?

My first and only thought:

1. First remove the data from the $n$ devices: they are obviously flawed, and should not partake in the analysis.
2. Then, use the remaining $k - n $ devices to fit a data on the response which corresponds to the percentage of time spent in the second category.
   3 . Then use the $k$ removed devices as a test data. If the fitted model accurately predicts the response measured on this test data, this would seem to confirm the hypothesis.

Or, maybe not?

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility: assign the $n$ abnormal devices to one group (A) and the $k-n$ "normal" devices to another group (B). For each device, calculate the quantity $y$ equal to the sum of the times reported for the first two depth categories. Your hypothesis then implies $\overline{y_A} = \overline{y_B}$ and you can apply an appropriate statistical test comparing two sample means. Note that neither this approach nor the one you suggest can confirm your hypothesis. I think the best you can do is show that the data are not inconsistent with your hypothesis.